# Multi-ordering for multi-uses depending on ZIP/POSTAL CODE

Tags: order

I am currently working on a eCommerce site that is supposed to handle multi-ordering for multi-uses depending on ZIP/POSTAL CODE, as the products may or may not be available in different ZIPs.

Like, for example, the cart must have the ability to handle more than one order and each order might have a different recipient and each recipient might have a different zip from where to PICK or to DELIVER the product.

---

My question is how to graphically represent all this?

1: add a "continue shopping" button to cart. clicking on it, user will be asked to continue shopping for the same recipient or to shop for another recipient?
2: add multi-buttons to continue shop for same and or other recipient in cart?

Comment: I'm not seeing an actual question in here. What are you wanting advice on?

Comment: The question is how to graphically represent all this?

Answer (score 1):

Magento (an e-commerce platform) provides a "Ship to Multiple Addresses" option that's worth studying:

*"As a customer is in their shopping cart, they simply select "One Address" or "Multiple Addresses" before proceeding to a check-out page.
Selecting "Multiple Shipping" allows them to select a shipping address for each individual item.
Once they've entered a location once, it becomes available for all other items in the order as well in the account's address book for any future transactions.
Each address is then organized for you (the website owner) as separate orders, keeping your fulfillment system uncluttered."*

[image]

Link to more info: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/inside-magento-6-ship-to-multiple-addresses/
http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/inside-magento-6-ship-to-multiple-addresses/

Answer (score 0):

Even that those features are useful for that specific ecommerce, they seem kind of complicated. I suggest you to separate the process into two different 'stages' of the purchase: the purchase itself & delivery.

I would use different ZIPCODE carts as different lists, like wish lists. The user adds items for each recipient's cart, one at a time. Always leaving a link for switch the shopping list.

With the delivery address ZIPCODE, I'd use Best Buy's sollution for delivery options: make the user choose between Shipping and Store Pickup (leaving shipping disabled when necessary).

Don't know if I was able to help you with your question, but I really think that the user shouldn't make multi-purchases at the same moment... Unless it is a specific kind of user, that is already used to it.

**Best Buy Sollution:**

[image]